# Basics of triangles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry

If a triangle with maximum area  is inscribed in a circle, what type of triangle should it be?The answer is equilateral triangle but why?

Comment: The actual question goes like this: If one vertex of the triangle having maximum area that can be inscribed in the  circle |z-i|=5 is 3-3i then find the other vertices of the triangle .how do we know about the triangle with the largest area inside the given circle

Answer (score 1):

Consider a triangle ABC inscribed in a circle as a chord AB with C a moveable point on an arc of the circle (either will do).  Let AB be the 'base', then the area of the triangle is 'base' * 'height' / 2, where 'height' depends on where C is.  Imagining AB as horizontal, 'height' is maximized by placing C at the top point of the arc; this forces the triangle to be isoceles, with respect to base AB.  Repeat this for bases AC, BC, then the area is maximized by an equilateral triangle.